# Spring Boot Scheduler using java pojo/enum in cron

Tags: spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I want to use java expression inside cron for scheduling in Spring Boot.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${FileConfig.FileEnum.getScheduleTime()}" )
public void scheduleFetchFiles() {

...//method body

}
```

Is there a direct way to use pojo object or enum value in cron?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just want any way to inject the value. You are betting of just setting it via property than the return value of a method.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${scheduledTimes.cron}")
public void scheduleFetchFiles() {

...//method body

}
```

Where scheduledTimes.cron is specified in your properties.